# Upper bound of $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)...\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, upper-lower-bounds

In a calculus book that I'm reading, there is a problem as follows:

> Prove that this sequence $x_n=\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)...\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)$ is monotonic, bounded and then converges.

I can prove that this sequence is increasing, but I found no way to find the upper bound for $x_n$.

Please give me some hint to find the upper bound, and may be the limit of this sequence also.

Thanks

Comment: Equivalently to Axel's anwer, you can use $1+x \le e^x$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1118666 – these and more similar questions can be found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x_n%3D%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cright)%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B4%7D%5Cright)...%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5En%7D%5Cright)%24)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1005763.

Comment: How can you find out those link? I tried to search before posting this question, but I found nothing then I posted it.

Comment: @anonimo Try to look at the right part of your post there are related post. If you do not find something then try to use the site suggested by MartinR.

Answer (score 1):

Let,

$$u_n = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1+ \dfrac{1}{2^i}\right)$$

**Hint:**

Calculate $\ln(u_n)$ and use that $\ln(1+x) \leq x$ for all $x$.

Once you've shown that $(u_n)_n$ is bounded, as $(u_n)_n$ is an increasing sequence it follows that $u_n$ converges by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Thank you. Can we calculate the limit Axel?

Comment: You're welcome. Well it was not resquested in your problem. I will have to think about it, but it seems to be a much harder problem.

Comment: I think so, when I first look at this product, I found no intuition to imagine about its limit. Btw, I have requested in my question  :) (..."may be the limit of this sequence also.")

Comment: Yes me neither, it is rather simple to check that it converges. Yes I saw that :) but I meant it was not a question of your calculus book. If I ever find something I'll let you know.

Comment: Just some more personal thought on this problem: It appears in the problem section after the lesson of monotonic sequences in the 1st chapter of convergence of sequences. The student is supposed not to know anything about the derivative (to prove that ln(1+x)<x, or the convergence to e of (1+1/n)^n. I see no reason for the authors to put this problem there, unless there is a more elementary solution?

Comment: You might take a look at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1119220/745510) that does not involve logarithms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126829/discussion-between-axel-and-anonimo).

Answer (score 1):

Using GM-AM you get

$$\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac 1{2^k}\right)< \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n < e$$

Comment: The product is the so-called Pochhammer function
$$\frac{1}{2} \left(-1;\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n+1}$$